# Random unique integer values

Tags: matlab, random, matrix

Is there an alternative to `randi`, I need **unique** integer values. Using `randi` the `PianoSperimentale` matrix may contain repeated integer values.

```
lover_bound = 10;
upper_bound = 180;
steps = 10;
NumeroCestelli = 8; 

livello = [lover_bound:steps:upper_bound];
L = length(livello);
n_c = 500 000
NumeroCestelli = 8

randIdxs = randi([1,L],n_c,NumeroCestelli);
PianoSperimentale = single(livello(randIdxs));
```

The alternative needs to be fast and support very large matrix. In the past i was using this:

```
[PianoSperimentale] = combinator(L,NumeroCestelli,'c','r');

for i=1:L
    PianoSperimentale(PianoSperimentale==i)=livello(i);
end
```

but is too slow and painfull. (see [Combinator](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24325-combinator-combinations-and-permutations))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is:

```
randsample(10,3)
```

gives a *vector* of 3 integers taken from 1 to 10, without replacement.

If you need a *matrix* instead of a vector:

```
matrix = NaN(8,12);
matrix(:) = randsample(1000,numel(matrix));
```

gives an 8x12 matrix of unique integers taken from 1 to 1000.

The function `randsample` is in the Statistics Toolbox. If you don't have it you can use `randperm` instead, as noted by @RodyOldenhuis and @Dan (see @Dan's answer).

Comment: +1, although note that this is part of the Statistics toolbox.

Comment: I'm a bit struggling with this approach. Using the above example    
     `n_c = ceil((factorial(L+NumeroCestelli-1))/(factorial(NumeroCestelli)*factorial(L-1)));`I should return a `1081575x8` matrix with no equa rows. So `[10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80]` is equa to `[80 70 60 50 40 30 20 10]` and then only one should be in my matrix. This should be working right? `matrix = randsample(upper_bound,numel(NaN(n_c,NumeroCestelli)));`

Comment: If I understood correctly: the presence of `[10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80]`  in a row should preclude any permutation of those 8 values in any other row. That's _very different_ from what you asked. And apparently harder. If that's what you want, I suggest you post it as a separate question

Answer (score 1):

Also if you don't have the stats toolbox then you could use `randperm`:

```
randperm(m, k) + n - 1
```

This will also give you `k` random integers between `n` and `n+m` without replacement